# Matching up tables to group properly

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Im having a lot of trouble counting the amount of vendors per county, per state in our database.  Was hoping someone could help me out.

I have one table called vendors which lists the vendors id (key) and their current assignments.

the next table is called postal codes and the columns i need from it are postalcode, FIPS (this is a code for counties in the US) and state. this is simply a list of possible states, postal codes and fips

my third table is vendoraddresses, which lists the addresses of each vendor but does not have a county or fips column or else this would be very easy. this is linked to the vendor table through the vendorid key

the final table is counties, which has the county name for each fips code lined up in rows (ie: 12345 = county name)

im having trouble working with all of these tables together to accurately count the vendors per county per state.  i feel like this really shouldn't be so hard but i hit a mental block i guess.  Below is what i have so far, but its not what i need. Im wondering if a union or something like that would be a better choice to get all these tables together.

```
SELECT

va.state
,pc.fips
,count(v.vendorid) as vendors


FROM 
Vendors v
join vendoraddresses va on va.vendorid = v.vendorid
join postalcodes pc on pc.postalcode = va.postalcode
group by va.state, fips
order by va.state, fips
```

so with some help ive tried to make some progress:

```
SELECT 
State1
,County
,COUNT(Vendor) as Vendors
FROM
(
SELECT
c.name as County, pc.State as State1, v.VendorID as Vendor
FROM 
Vendors v
join vendorserviceareas vsa on vsa.vendorid = v.vendorid
join vendorserviceareaentries vsae on vsae.vendorserviceareaid =     vsa.vendorserviceareaid 
join counties c on c.fips = vsae.fips
join postalcodes pc on pc.fips = c.fips

union 

select c.name as county, s.name as state1, vsa.Vendorid as Vendor from states s
join counties c on c.fips = s.fips
join vendorserviceareaentries vsae on vsae.fips = c.fips
join vendorserviceareas vsa on vsae.vendorserviceareaid = vsa.vendorserviceareaid 


)a
GROUP BY State1, County
Order BY State1, County
```

the additional tables i have added have the following columns (using abbreviations from query) vsa column 1 = serviceareaid (numerical ID), column 2 = vendorid (numerical id) column 3 =  description(text to describe area of service) (varchar(50))

the other table vsae has the following columns, column 1 = serviceareaid - same as above table, fips = county code (FK char (5)), and postal code (char (5))

and for some more info each service are could be called "california" or somehting like that, the system then has each state, then county, then postal codes within each county listed for a service area, this is where most of my issue is lying because i can get any number of postal codes per county so im getting a false count for what im trying to do.

My ultimate goal is to find out per county how many vendors i have without taking into account the postal codes of a county.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem that you are having is that postal codes can be in multiple counties.  You can check this by running the query:

```
select pc.fips, pc.postalcode, count(*)
from postalcodes pc
group by pc.fips, pc.postalcode
having count(*) > 1
order by 3 desc
```

This will give you a list of duplicates.  There are even postal codes that span states.

You will need to assign a postal code to a county.  If you have other information, such as population for the intersection of the postal code and county, you can try something like:

```
from (select pc.*
      from (select pc.*, row_number() over (partition by postal_code order by pop desc) as seqnum
            from postalcodes pc
           ) pc
      where seqnum = 1
     ) pc
```

This assigns to the postal code to the county where the larger population is.

Comment: thanks for the help, the other kind of info in the postal code table is longitude and latitude and timezone, not sure if that will work to do as you showed above.  i am ware that i am getting more than one postal code per county, but im trying to pull only 1 per county, would something as simple as putting in MAX(postalcode) for the county do the trick you think? then using it in the query correctly of course. just to list only 1 postal code per county? im going to try this and post my results if im getting somewhere with it.

Comment: @wondergoat77 . . . Yes, you can just use the MAX.  However, what you want is MAX(fips) per postal code.

Comment: ive edited my original post and added a new qeury.  Can you take a look and let me know if im the right path, not sure if i really needed the union i used or not. ive included some new tables to pull from as well, ill list those above too